# How to keep aspect ratio on matplotlib graphs while adding more objects to the figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Running the following code to generate two images, give me graphics with different aspect ratios, how can I enforce the graph aspect ratio of the graph? (not the image)

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import numpy.ma as ma 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

msize=25
rrange=int(msize**0.5)
jump=3
start=int(jump/2)

X,Y=np.meshgrid(range(0,msize),range(0,msize))
dat=np.random.rand(msize,msize)*rrange

msk=np.zeros_like(dat)
msk[start::jump,start::jump].fill(1)
mdat=msk*dat
mdat[mdat==0]=np.nan
mmdat = ma.masked_where(np.isnan(mdat),mdat)

fargs={ 'edgecolor': 'w',
        'facecolor': 'w',
        'frameon': True,
        }

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),**fargs)


cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
cmap.set_bad(color='#cccccc', alpha=1.)

plot = plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,mmdat,cmap=cmap)

plot.axes.set_ylim(0,msize-1)                                                                                                               
plot.axes.set_xlim(0,msize-1)

fargs['bbox_inches']='tight'

fig.savefig("masked100.png",dpi=100,**fargs)

plt.colorbar()
fig.savefig("masked101.png",dpi=100,**fargs)
```

The first save generates image like this:
[image: image with sqare aspect ratio]

The second one generates this:
[image: image with rectangular aspect ratio]

As we can see, each "pixel" in the second image is slightly non squared (squeezed at his sides). How can I preserve the graph aspect ratio while adding new graphic informations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a call to `set_aspect()` after adding the colorbar:

```
# ...
plot.axes.set_ylim(0,msize-1)                                                                                                               
plot.axes.set_xlim(0,msize-1)
# 
plot.axes.set_aspect('equal')
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The smallest modification to your script that you need to make is two things.  Add

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10),**fargs)
plt.axis('equal')
```

after you create the figure. This will force the x-axis and y-axis to have the same step size.  That alone will result in a large amount of white space above and below the resultant mpl figure.

[image: after plt.axis('equal')]

You will also need to manually resize the figure (I doubt there is a way to automatically do this). You can do this by calling `fig.set_size_inches(10,8)` before plt.colorbar:

```
fig.savefig("masked100.png",dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight', **fargs)
fig.set_size_inches(10,8)
plt.colorbar()
fig.savefig("masked101.png",dpi=100, bbox_inches='tight', **fargs)
```

Note that I came to the figure size of (10,8) by trial and error.  The resultant figure looks like this:

[image]

Please see this jupyter notebook for the source code and images: https://gist.github.com/ericdill/62e555bd82d76fb93e30

You should also consider using the object oriented (OO) interface instead of using the functions in `pyplot` exclusively, mostly because making heavy use of `pyplot` can have some unintended consequences, as the global state that it relies in can be wonky at times.  You can see the changes to your script that are required to use the OO interface in the above link to a jupyter notebook.